# Terminating app due to uncaught NSException of 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, segue

I have two **Xcode** projects (SampleMain, SampleTest) programmed in **Swift** which is taken into a single workspace called Sample. Then I try to merge SampleMain's `UIStoryboard` (Main) to SampleTest's `UIStoryboard` (Main) using a button via `UIStoryboard` reference. When I run the app no exception is caught until the button used for segue is pressed. As the button pressed the app is terminated with an `NSException` in the console log.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a
>   view controller with identifier 'test'' * First throw call stack: ( 0
>   CoreFoundation 0x000000010e17334b exceptionPreprocess + 171 1
>   libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000010b5c021e objc_exception_throw + 48 2 UIKit
>   0x000000010c2622bf -[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] +
>   0 3 UIKit 0x000000010c048392 -[UIStoryboardViewControllerPlaceholder
>   initWithCoder:] + 143 4 UIKit 0x000000010c098dbd
>   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 684 5 UIKit 0x000000010c098b0a
>   -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 98 6 UIKit 0x000000010be9d15c -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 178 7 UIKit 0x000000010c098dbd UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 684 8 UIKit 0x000000010c098f73
>   UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1122 9 UIKit 0x000000010c098b0a
>   -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 98 10 UIKit 0x000000010be9c300 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1249 11 UIKit 0x000000010c2621ab -[UIStoryboard
>   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 181 12 UIKit
>   0x000000010c269fab -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate
>   instantiateOrFindDestinationViewControllerWithSender:] + 90 13 UIKit
>   0x000000010c26a1ff -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 52 14
>   UIKit 0x000000010c26a4df -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156
>   15 UIKit 0x000000010ba91b88 -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83 16 UIKit 0x000000010bc172b2
>   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67 17 UIKit 0x000000010bc175cb -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444 18 UIKit 0x000000010bc164c7 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668 19 UIKit
>   0x000000010baff0d5 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747 20 UIKit
>   0x000000010bb007c3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011 21 UIKit
>   0x000000010baada33 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371 22 UIKit
>   0x000000010c29fb6d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248 23
>   UIKit 0x000000010c298817 __handleEventQueue + 4879 24 CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010e118311
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 17 25 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e0fd59c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556 26
>   CoreFoundation 0x000000010e0fca86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918 27
>   CoreFoundation 0x000000010e0fc494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420 28
>   GraphicsServices 0x000000011001ca6f GSEventRunModal + 161 29 UIKit
>   0x000000010ba8ff34 UIApplicationMain + 159 30 SampleMain
>   0x000000010afe4e2f main + 111 31 libdyld.dylib 0x000000010f09d68d
>   start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of
>   type NSException (lldb)

I have configured the storyboard reference in the following manner:

[image: storyboard reference]

SampleMain - Main.storyboard

[image: SampleMain - Main.storyboard]

What am I doing wrong? If my approach to merging two storyboards of two different projects is incorrect; please explain a method to do so.

Comment: Your error line is pretty clear! " reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'test'' * First throw call stack "

Comment: You've not implemented an identifier for view controller